# Is it possible to pass values from a Razor component to a Razor page?

Tags: model-view-controller, components, blazor, razor-pages

I'm integrating Razor components into ASP.NET Core Razor Pages in my Blazor Webassembly project in order to keep the UI consistent between the client and server.

One of these components is a multiselect dropdown and I'm having a really hard time getting the model of my Razor page to bind to the values in my component.

Is there another way I can pass data from my component to the page? I know it's easy to pass data the other way via parameters, but I'm struggling to work out how to do it the other way around.